# Type constructor for making objects partially readonly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a a type constructor for making certain properties of on object readonly? For example:

```
type ReadonlyByKey<T extends {} , K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in T]: P extends K > Readonly<T[P]> : T[P]
}
```

(Which doesn't work since we're applying Readonly here to  `T[P]` not  `{ P:  T[P] }`)

Something that behaves like a combination of Pick/Exclude and Partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually combine `Readonly`, `Pick` and `Omit` to get the desired effect:

```
type ReadonlyByKey<T extends {} , K extends keyof T> = Readonly<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGATA9gOwDYgEIgNIRAB4AVKCAD2AlUQGcoBvAXygBopczLq6oBrAsgBmUYgD4oAXlgIUGIgAUAlgGM+JdrjESAZFADyAWyXANHMQFgAUNdCQoASSmNrUN1HgAuKLWAAnJVQAcwBuV3cAI29fAODrJmtbcGgYZwdEQjgkNEwcfCIHdgByCKLtJPt0kglpZig9BigAbQUoQP5BEWIAXW9iFu6WIA)

The first intersection constituent picks the readonly members, while the second one picks the other members

**Edit**

A version to remove by type would be:

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P: never
}[keyof T]

type ReadonlyByKey<T extends {} , K extends keyof T> = Readonly<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>
type ReadonlyByType<T, V> = ReadonlyByKey<T, KeyOfType<T, V>>
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAVcEA8KA0UBqAfFALxQDeAsAFBS1QDaAClAJYB2UA1vAPZJQoAugC4BTQVAgAPYBDYATAM74oAfiiNRbCADcIAJ2oBfetxB8Bg6tVCQoAJQgBDeTzYAbEACEQcEFkkZOSVyIyhcGEDZBWUzCxQiUkcXN08MRhYAY04sCIIiADIoBABbFmBc2AIbdAdnVw9vEDRISsISOpTGnz9Kv2QWzBwoNgBXEoAjA3zrKltoAEkOyho6J1FFYH12AHMAbmo6KAmtcanDKiNZ+YcOhfkMZIbPHvgMBdwAcgnPmbna+5YRKhKBFMgMZjsLi8fhCUQocRhIA)

Comment: That is correct. I'm going to adjust my question though. I realised I needed to be able to do this based on the type of the property and not the key.

Comment: @chautelly You can use the type above to get what you want. Added how you could do this. I think the solution is simpler than the one you suggested.

Comment: Thank you! Much more readable then what I came up with ha, ha. I think you meant to replace `number` with `V` in `ReadonlyByType`

Comment: @chautelly yeah, i meant `V`, rush to post, thanks 

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with to do this based on a given type rather than a set of keys:

I'm sure this can be simplified.

```
type KeysOfType<T, O> = {
  [P in keyof O]: O[P] extends T ? P : never;
};

type Values<T> = T extends { [k: string]: infer V } ? V : never;

type State = {
  message: string;
  counter: number;
};

type ReadonlyIfType<T, O> = Readonly<
  Omit<O, Exclude<keyof O, Values<KeysOfType<T, O>>>>
> &
  Omit<O, keyof Omit<O, Exclude<keyof O, Values<KeysOfType<T, O>>>>>;

type WhatDidIDo = ReadonlyIfType<number, State>;

declare const wtf: WhatDidIDo 

wtf.message = 'Hello' // Does not error and should not
wtf.counter = 4 // Fails and shoud
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)